# vimdiff is not launching when I try to resolve a git merge conflict

Tags: git, vim, merge

I am using git and trying to merge a branch which is causing a mergeconflict.
I have tried to configure `vimdiff` as the mergetool with

```
git config merge.tool vimdiff
git config merge.conflictstyle diff3
git config mergetool.prompt false
```

Here is what is happening

```sh
$ git merge master
CONFLICT (rename/delete): dev_tools+env_config/gnome-term_+_bash+tmux.sh deleted in HEAD and renamed in master.  
Version master of dev_tools+env_config/gnome-term_+_bash+tmux.sh left in tree.
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

$ git status
On branch breaking_changes_test

You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

        added by them:      dev_tools+env_config/gnome-term_+_bash+tmux.sh

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

$ git mergetool
Merging:
dev_tools+env_config/gnome-term_+_bash+tmux.sh

Deleted merge conflict for 'dev_tools+env_config/gnome-term_+_bash+tmux.sh':
  {local}: deleted
  {remote}: created file
Use (c)reated or (d)eleted file, or (a)bort?
```

When I ran `git mergetool`, I was expecting `vimdiff` to open showing the differences between the conflicted file.
How can I get `vimdiff` to launch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vimdiff isn't launching because there is no such conflict to resolve. It is just a case of a file being there in one branch and not being there in another. Git is simply asking which file to keep, the created one or the deleted one.

Comment: there are both changes to the code and a file rename. Im trying to keep code from the current branch, but this process is only giving me the option of the file from the merged branch or an empty file

Comment: The `mergetool` comes up if a conflict is **within** a file and not on the whole file itself (delete, rename, create).

Comment: @barthel thanks, yes I think thats what happened. whilst there were *changes* to actually only the code - there was a quasi-conflict on the file rename - so your explanation makes sense

Comment: @user4668401 your welcome. Mark my comment as useful if you like. ;-)